# Select table records from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a requirement to get all the records from a table but the condition is I want to get the table name from another table. Any suggestions on how I can do it?

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT table_name
          FROM table_containing_table_names
         WHERE table_id = 17) AS Records;
```

Comment: You need dynamic query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need dynamic sql for such things.

**An example**

> ```
> create table foo (
> id int auto_increment primary key, 
> foo int
> );
> insert into foo (foo) values (21);
>
> create table bar (
> id int auto_increment primary key, 
> bar int
> );
> insert into bar (bar) values (42);
> ```

> ```
> create table table_containing_table_names (
> table_id int primary key, 
> table_name varchar(30)
> );
>
> insert into table_containing_table_names
> (table_id, table_name) values 
> (21, 'foo'), (42,'bar');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE getDataFromTableId (IN id INT)
> BEGIN
>   SET @table_id = id;
>   SET @table_name = (
>             select table_name 
>             from table_containing_table_names 
>             where table_id = @table_id);
>   
>   IF @table_name IS NOT NULL
>   THEN
>     SET @stmt = CONCAT('select * from `', @table_name, '`;');
>   
>     PREPARE stmt FROM @stmt;
>     EXECUTE stmt;
>     DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
>   END IF;
> END;
> ```

> ```
> call getDataFromTableId(21);
> ```
>
> ```
> id | foo
> -: | --:
>  1 |  21
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> call getDataFromTableId(42);
> ```
>
> ```
> id | bar
> -: | --:
>  1 |  42
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> call getDataFromTableId(888);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2b9c9a00bf6ba8016be03f362494fe66)*